# Neo4rs BoltType Float f64

Tags: rust, neo4j, bolt

I am using Neo4rs and I'm having troubles with floats. The following code

```
let mut result = graph.execute(
            query("CREATE (p:PERSON {height: $height}) RETURN p")
                .param("height", person.height)
```

Where `person.height` is a f64, will not compile due to

```
the trait bound `neo4rs::types::BoltType: std::convert::From<f64>` is not satisfied
```

Although, when I look at the repo, it does seem like it is implemented. I've been converting floats to strings and then back to floats but I think I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Although, when I look at the repo, it does seem like it is implemented.

Where do you see that? Because all I can see is a way to convert *from `BoltType` to `f64`* (so get f64 out of bolt I guess), not from `f64` into `BoltType`.

In fact there is [an open PR](https://github.com/yehohanan7/neo4rs/pull/11) which wants to add an f64->BoltType conversion (alongside conversion of `BoltType` from and into `Vec`).